# Understanding Apache Pig Performance

Tags: performance, join, filter, apache-pig

There are several parts involved in the queries in this question. First there are two schemas:

```sql
data = FOREACH source GENERATE
    json#'id_str' AS post_id:chararray,
    json#'user'#'id_str' AS user_id:chararray,
    json#'created_at_str' AS tstamp_str:chararray,
    FLATTEN(json#'entities'#'hashtags') AS hashtag:chararray;

stopwords = FOREACH another_source GENERATE
    token AS stopword_hashtag:chararray;
```

`stopwords` table contains some duplicates and nulls, so the first thing I did is

```sql
stopwords = FILTER stopwords BY stopword_hashtag IS NOT NULL;
stopwords = DISTINCT stopwords;
```

Then I want to filter out the `stopwords` from the `data`'s hashtags, so I do the join with filter, followed by a projection back to `data`:

```sql
joined = JOIN data BY hashtag LEFT, stopwords BY stopword_hashtag;
joined = FILTER joined BY stopwords::stopword_hashtag IS NULL;

data = FOREACH joined GENERATE
    data::post_id AS post_id:chararray,
    data::user_id AS user_id:chararray,
    parse_time(data::tstamp_str) AS tstamp:long,
    data::hashtag AS hashtag:chararray;
```

`parse_time(char array)` is a `Jython` UDF I wrote to convert datetime string into UNIX timestamp long. After all these I will do a group+sort:

```sql
user_groups = FOREACH (GROUP data BY user_id) GENERATE
    group AS user_id:chararray,
    data.(hashtag, tstamp) AS time_series:bag{tuple:(tag:chararray,tstamp:long)};
user_groups = FOREACH user_groups {
    sorted = ORDER time_series BY tstamp ASC;
    GENERATE user_id, sorted;
}
```

All of these is in one Pig script. I am having performance issue with running this process on large data. I know it works on small toy examples. For large examples where both `data` and `stopwords` are long, it takes up too much memory and becomes very slow.

As far as I can understand, I am doing filtering as early as possible, also doing only left-join. Any suggestions for performance optimization?

---

My apology for the late update. I have tried @Ran Locar approach, which works like a charm!

There was a bug in Pig during the filter step:

```sql
output = FILTER data_with_count BY from_stopwords_count==0;
```

which reported

```sql
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

It took me some time to figure out a workaround. I solved it by explicitly casting both from_stopwords_count and 0 to long, that is:

```sql
 data_with_count = FOREACH data_with_count GENERATE
     $0.., (long) from_stopwords_count AS from_stopwords_count:long;
 output = FILTER data_with_count BY from_stopwords_count==0L;
```

I guess I could have casted both to int, which possibly would give improvement in performance, but I feel safer with long given the size of the table I have.

Some statistics of my inputs:

1. source of data is 1.1TB in gzip format
2. source of stopwords is 400GB in gzip format, but I am only taking one column of it really.

The query runs for 2.3 hours, taking 550GB memory and 180 vcores. Successful completion at the end, which really saved my day!

Comment: shouldn't that be a `left outer` join? By default left would mean inner join, which would never have any records with  `stopwords::stopword_hashtag IS NULL`

Comment: @rahulbmv I thought left join is equivalent to left outer join. At least that's how I have been thinking about left join in SQL. Let me go back and check pig documentations.

Comment: @rahulbmv `JOIN table BY col LEFT` is a left outer join in Apache Pig according to 0.14.0 Doc (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#join-outer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to avoid the join between stopwords and data altogether. Essentially what you need to do is:

- No need for the DISTINCT, or the filtering of stop words.
- get DATA and STOPWORDS to share the same schema

  ```
  stopwords = FOREACH another_source GENERATE
  '' as post_id,
  '' as user_id,
  '' as tstamp_str,
  token AS hashtag:chararray,
  0 as from_data,
  1 as from_stopwords;
  ```
- add the from_data and from_stopwords fields to the schema of data

  ```
  data = FOREACH data GENERATE
  $0..,
  1 as from_data,
  0 as from_stopwords;
  ```
- UNION the two relations

  ```
  data_with_stopwords = UNION data, stopwords;
  ```
- group by token. In each group you will have rows from both relations.

  ```
  data_with_stopwords_and_counts = foreach (group data_with_stopwords by hashtag) generate
  $0.., SUM(data_with_stopwords.from_data) as from_data_sum, SUM(data_with_stopwords.from_stopwords) as from_stopwords_sum;
  ```

each row will now have the group key, all the rows belonging to the group, and two numbers. You want only the rows where from_stopwords_sum == 0, as those rows do not appear in the stop words list (this is why you no longer need the DISTINCT... you don't mind words being in the stop words more than once; you will simply get the from_stopwords_sum >= 1, and disregard that row)

- filter by from_stopwords_sum == 0 and flatten the list

  ```
  data_with_stopwords_and_counts = foreach (filter data_with_stopwords_and_counts by from_stopwords_sum==0) generate
  flatten($1);
  ```

This approach replaces the JOIN by a GROUP BY. When I tested it on many many GBs of data, it finished in <10mins compared to a few hours using joins. Your rows will have the extra sum fields in the end, but you can remove them afterwards.

Comment: Let me try on my dataset this afternoon and report back the improvement in performance in my case. But either way I think this is ingenious!

Comment: Some questions I have for you, if you would kindly give me hints: what is the rationale of your query? Why is this faster and more efficient? What did you read to get that piece of knowledge? I would love to get as good as you are!

Comment: @Mai, I'm super glad it worked. I'll tell you how I came up with it - in my job (Outbrain; the 'you may also want to read' content recommendations; the good ones. Not the ones with naked women...), I often need 'users who visited on both days' and 'users who visited in a certain period, but not in the two weeks before that'.
For the first query, a left join makes sense; for the second one, you're only interested in the 'end result' - visits, or no visits. So it makes a lot of sense to summarize the count of visits in each period per users and filter.
Your case is really the same... cont

Comment: problem, stated otherwise.
As for 'Why' it works faster - joins in Hadoop can be either Map side (Big table joined with small table that fits in memory) or Reduce side (send all values for the same key, to the same reducer). I read enough documentation (https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/perf.html) to understand performance of joins is a big issue (see how many 'tweaks' are available); on the other hand, I know group-by is probably the simplest operation (think word count, the basic map reduce example). So if you can replace one with the other - it's probably a good idea.... cont

Comment: one important thing to remember; a special feature of Pig that allows this trick, is that when you do a group-by, you get the group-key, followed by a bag containing ALL THE TUPLES belonging to that key. Which means group-by does not lead to information loss. In SQL it does; if a field was not part of your key you won't see it in the result. So you can't use the same pattern. (view this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiIjEzW3br8 helped me a lot). Best of luck!!!